# Write continuous command output to file without ending the command

Tags: windows, io-redirection

To use `command > file.txt`, the command has to stop running to write its output to file.txt.

I have a command that will run for indefinitely until I shutdown my pc (automated). I want its output to be logged so I can look at it later. Is this possible?

I've tried `&>` which doesn't work on my windows machine (I have the git bash commands installed). And `2>` doesn't change anything.

Edit:

The file, `command.sh` contains this:

```
python ../tool.py -dev
```

This tool.py will run until it is terminated (^C).

I also cannot edit the python program because it is regularly pulled from a git repository I cannot write to.

Edit2:
I'm running Windows 7 and I have [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) installed which installs many linux function such as `ls` etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to Unix/Linux.

Comment: It's the linux bash commands

Comment: What is the command? The output would normally be flushed every once in a while, but some commands are line-buffered so that every complete line is written at once, or can be _made to be_ line-buffered.

Comment: It is a sh file that calls just had `python file.py` and some arguments.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your previous comment “It is a sh file that calls just had python file.py and some arguments”, can you help by re-writing. Also edit the question.

Comment: Linux or MS-Windows? Bash is gnu. Used in Gnu/Linux, and Cygwin, and WSL (Gnu/Linux, but with Linux removed, for MS_windows). Which Os are you using, and what Gnu subsystem?

Comment: Please update your question to actually show a use-case which recreates the issue.  Your presumption that output redirection (`>`) only writes upon process termination is incorrect.

Comment: Just a note: It is bad form in Unix to have file extensions of executables. This is because the caller, should not have to know what language a program is written in, and it should be possible to re-write in a different language, without having to change the programs that call it.

Comment: So this is not running on a Linux or Unix operating system, is not _actually_ running any of the aforementioned Cygwin commands, but rather is running a Win32 Python program on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer from @ctrl-alt-delor is correct, but doesn't address your edited question - and the edit was quite significant. And it seems from the comments that the question has constraints that are still "coming out".

At this stage of the discussion, two facts seem prominent. And from those two facts there is a conclusion from what I can see:

1. In a Python program, you have complete control over how and when output data is "flushed" to a file. However, you must exercise that control from within the Python program that produces the output.
2. You say you "can't edit the python files", and can't edit them after you pull them from the repo.

If these are the facts, then two things would seem to be true:

1. The answer to your question is: "No, you can't do what you want to do."
2. Your inability to edit the files before you execute them is based on a rule or an agreement you've entered into. I say this because there is nothing "technically" preventing you from doing so - or at least you've not explained it. If your Windows-based tools are not up to the job, I assure you there are other Windows-based tools that are. We're not talking about rocket science really - you download a group of files via git, and you can programmatically or manually edit them.

But please forgive me if I've jumped to an erroneous conclusion. I'm sure someone here can help, but we should have all of the facts first - so we don't waste our time chasing rabbits.

Comment: I guess no logging then. Or spend time automating the changes of the python programs. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, so sorry, but that's the bottom line without more info.

Answer (score 1):

> To use `command > file.txt`, the command has to stop running to write its output to file.txt.

This statement is completely false. The output is written, whenever the command flushes its output stream. This also happens when a command exits.

Therefore ensure that the command flushes its output stream regularly.

Comment: How can I make the command flush more often?

Comment: Add to the question, what the command is. Is it a standard command? Is it one that you wrote? What language? etc.

Comment: I've added the file contents.

Comment: have a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/537980

Comment: Sadly I can't edit the python files

Comment: You can copy it, then edit and run the copy. If the program is keeping hold of data until it exits, then you have to change the program.

Comment: But whenever I pull it from the repository again I can't manually edit the files again.

Comment: That seems like a new question. I would think that if you can write a file, then you can edit it, but MS_Windows is a strange beast.